# Name of clicked ListView Element Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

how can I put the Name of my clicked ListView Item in an Intent?

```
      barlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      

            Intent i = new Intent(Barlocator.this, Barinfo.class);
            i.putExtra( , );
            startActivity(i);
            } 
        });
```

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, just need to define a name for your extra argument, and retrieve the actual Name to put into it. We don't know what your Adapter contains, but start from here:

```
final Adapter adapter = parent.getAdapter();
final YourItemType item = adapter.getItem( position );

final Name = item.getNameSomehow();
```

Comment: I meant the type, are they just Strings? If so replace YourItemType with String and you will get the string at the `position` position.

Comment: What do I have to change in that case (SQL database)? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: I don't understand the issue with the Adapter? Why do I need one here?

Comment: An adapter is the glue that joins a collection (variable) with a visual interface like ListView (UI). You've received a click on the item visible at the `position` position, so you ask the adapter to get the actual value that the collection holds for that position.

Comment: Could you give me an example where you put that stuff in my code? Sry I'm developing my first serious App... ;)

Answer (score 1):

take a string like **String s="item"** the use like this

```
String listItem=adapter.getItem(position);
i.putExtra( s+position,listItem );
```

Comment: barlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      
    
final Adapter adapter = parent.getAdapter();
String listItem=adapter.getItem(position); 
Intent i = new Intent(Barlocator.this, Barinfo.class);
i.putExtra( s+position,listItem );
startActivity(i);
    
} 
});

Comment: S will act like key.S has value "item" when it will be concat with any numeric it will become item1,item2,item3.....these will act like keys.and ur value will be represented by listItem.hope u understand.

Comment: What is `position` ? It seems like an undefined variable to me.